# VSTO obtain MailItem reference of Click event sender

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I am currently developing a **VSTO** application which calls a Windows Forms 'Wizard' like UI. I have been extensively looking throughout MSDN and Google but could not directly find an answer to my question:

How do you obtain the *MailItem* reference of the currently invoked *MailItem* object?

Scenario:

User opens an e-mail. Once within the e-mail, my custom Ribbon button is active. User invokes the Click event on the Button. I suppose there is some sort of a cast but I am failing to see what to cast to. I assume *sender* will not be the *MailItem* but the UI thread.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
Private Sub Customs_Click(sender As System.Object, e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Customs.Click

    Dim tsWizard As New TimeStampWizard()
    tsWizard.Show()

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Dim buttonClicked As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton
        buttonClicked = CType(sender, RibbonButton)
        Dim inspectorContext = CType(buttonClicked.Ribbon.Context, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector)
        Dim currentMail = CType(inspectorContext.CurrentItem, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)

        Dim tsWizard As New TimeStampWizard(currentMail)
        tsWizard.Show()

Did the job for me. Figured it out and googled a bit more and found out the following. In case anyone else ever pops up with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim buttonClicked As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton 
buttonClicked = CType(sender, RibbonButton) 
Dim inspectorContext = CType(buttonClicked.Ribbon.Context, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) 

Dim currentMail = CType(inspectorContext.CurrentItem, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
```

Did the job :)